# Show that $|\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have to prove that $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})=\{E \subset \mathbb{R}:\text{ E is meaurable}\} $ has the same number of elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$
($|\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|$). How could I start to show this property?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't, because it is not true. Indeed, for any set $X$, we have $|P(X)| > |X|$.

Comment: Sorry, the title was wrong. Try to take a look now.

Comment: Looking at the cardinality of the collection of the measurable subsets of the Cantor set will handle the difficult direction, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be the cantor set. It's measure is $0$. Since Lebesgue measure is complete every subset of $C$ is again a measure zero set. Also $C$ is uncountable. Hence there is exist a surjective map from $P(C)$ to $P(\mathbb{R})$. Can you complete from here?

> $P(C) \subset M(\mathbb{R}) \subset P(\mathbb{R})$
> $P(C)$ and $P(\mathbb{R})$ have the same cardinality by the above argument. Hence $|M(\mathbb{R})|=|P(\mathbb{R})|$

$\mathbf{Edit}$: By $C$ is uncountable I meant $C$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality. That is there is a bijection between $C$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is it generally true that if $X$ is an uncountable set there is a surjection $P(X) \mapsto P(\mathbf R)$?

Comment: Oh the uncountable cardinality should match. Wait I'll edit my answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Only to be sure at all, why can we state that exists a surjective map from $\mathcal{P}(C) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: @Nabla because if there is a bijection say $f$ between $C$ and $\mathbb{R}$ then you can produce a bijection $\Phi: P(C) \rightarrow P(\mathbb{R})$ by defining $\Phi(A) = f(A)$ where $A\: \in P(C)$ and $f(A)=\{f(a) : a\:\in A\}$

Comment: thank you! @nrynn

Comment: @Nabla You're welcome :-)

Comment: Isn't the argument not that $C$ is uncountable but that there is a bijection between $C$ and $\mathbb {R} $, considering that the continuum hypothesis isn't a theorem ?